# Need help getting percent of a number

Tags: java, numbers

Basically in this website you can get credits and buy stuff with them. If you keep the credits in your bank, you get 0.12% added daily:

[image: Picture to understand this.]

I wanted to code a quick program to calculate this but I need help, here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("| NextGenUpdate Credits |");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("Credits: ");
        double credits = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Days: ");
        int days = input.nextInt();

        int total = //DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE

        System.out.println("You will have have " + total + " credits in " + days + " days.");   

    }
}
```

Comment: [a quick google search for math daily compounded interest should help](https://www.google.de/search?q=math+compounded+interest&oq=math+compounded+interest&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1350j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=math+daily+compounded+interest+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you need to calculate the total credits after `days` days. For this, I would suggest `total` to be of `double` type, since it will most probably have floating point values.

You can do:

```
double total = credits * Math.pow((1+ 0.12/100d), days);
```

The formula for compounding is :

> A = P ( 1 + R/100)^n

Thus, your R is 0.12, P is `credits`, and n is `days`.

But since you want to use `int`, hence the value after decimal will be lost.

eg: 12.98 will give 12.

So, Instead, you can round off the value. You may use:

```
int total = (int)Math.rint(credits * Math.pow((1+ 0.12/100d), days));
```

Comment: I want them to input the days also. I used this code:
double total = credits * (1+ 0.12/100d);

and this was the output for 82 credits, no matter how many days they put:

You will have have 82.09840000000001 credits in 20 days.

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a simple mathematical solution. if you have 100 $ and want to give him 0.12% on his 100 $, you would need to multiply his 100 $ with 0.12% and add it to the original value. (or multiply it with 100.12%). Repeat for each day you want to do this. (Notice that the second day wouldn't be 100$, but 100.12$ and you calculate 100.12$ * 100.12%)

Comment: He wants a 0.12% increase, not 1.2% :)

Comment: Thanks, I moved the comma one over in my answer

Comment: Moreover, it is 0.12% daily, not only once.

Comment: Added a sentence regarding this, too